# Is the real part of Green's function directly observable?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, greens-functions

In many-body physics, the imaginary part of a Green's function corresponds to the signal intensity of some scattering experiments.

Does the real part of a Green function directly correspond to any experimental observable?

Comment: It's even worse : Green's function means nothing ! Once you get a Green's function, you got nothing. It's just an help to calculate observables. So your question is even meaningless unless you define an explicit Green's function. What forbids me to put a $i$ in front of its definition (such that $i^2=-1$) and to invert imaginary and real parts ? Answer : nothing ! Green's functions are like the wave functions: they have absolutely no meaning. So there is no answer to your question, or if you prefer, the answer is *yes*, for some Green's function and for some observables and for some models.

Comment: The standard convention is that the imaginary part of the Green function is the spectral function. Then i think that his question is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

Green's function itself is an abstract mathematical object, and *per se* is not directly observable. However, the observable quantities can be expressed in terms of Green's functions, thus giving us the idea of what the Green's function is like.

The most well-known case is the imaginary part of full Green's function, which corresponds to the density of states. E.g., if the Green's function of a level, broadened by interactions, is: 
$$ G(\omega) = \frac{1}{\omega -\epsilon_0 +\frac{i\Gamma}{2}},$$
(I took for simplicity a retarded Green's function, and take $\hbar =1$.)
then the associated density of states is
$$\rho(\omega) = -\frac{1}{\pi}\Im\left[G(\omega)\right] = \frac{\Gamma}{2\pi}\frac{1}{(\omega - \epsilon_0)^2+\frac{\Gamma^2}{4}}.$$

Considering a slightly more general case, the Green's function is given by
$$ G(\omega) = \frac{1}{\omega -\epsilon_0 +\Sigma(\omega)},$$
where $\Sigma(\omega)$ is itself a combination of Green's function. In a simple case of scattering from an entity with Green's function $g(\omega)$, we will have 
$$\Sigma(\omega) = |V|^2g(\omega),$$
which means that
$$\rho(\omega) = -\frac{1}{\pi}\Im\left[G(\omega)\right] = \frac{\Im[g(\omega)]}{\pi}\frac{1}{(\omega - \epsilon_0 - |V|^2\Re[g(\omega)])^2+\Im[g(\omega)]^2}.$$
If $\Im[g(\omega)]$ has a simple form (e.g., $\Im[g(\omega)]=\Gamma/2$) we can study $\Re[g(\omega)]$. Such study is in fact routinely done in all kinds of interference experiments, e.g., in the mesoscopic Aharonov-Bohm interferometers.